# Unknown 302 Redirect happening in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect

I'm dealing with a 302 Redirect when trying to access certain `network_hosts#show` pages.  It's not happening on all of them.  I've been trying to diagnose the issue for the last 5 hours and an befuddled.

Here's how it goes....

User clicks the following link in view `network_host/index.html.erb`:

```
<%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>'.html_safe, network_host_path(h.id), "data-toggle" => "tooltip", "title" => "View" %>
```

The controller `network_host#show` kicks in:

```
class NetworkHostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_company_and_locations

  def show
    @network_host = NetworkHost.find(params[:id])
    if @network_host
      @major_issues = get_host_issues(@network_host, @network_host.last_test, "major")
      @minor_issues = get_host_issues(@network_host, @network_host.last_test, "minor")
    end
  end
end
```

Which accesses helper methods in `helpers/application_helper.rb`:

```
def get_company_and_locations
  @company = current_user.company
  @devices =  Device.where(company_id: @company.id).order(name: :asc)
  @locations = if @company
    current_user.company_locations.order(:name)
  else
    []
  end
end


def get_host_issues(network_host, last_test, severity)
  get_company_and_locations
  # the issue_ids to remove since they are deferred
  deferred_ids = []
  @company.deferred_issues.each do |d|
    if d.network_host_id == network_host.id && d.expires_at.future?
      deferred_ids.push(d.issue_id)
    end
  end
  # figure out the issues
  results = last_test.results.select{|result| result.issue.severity == "#{severity}"}.collect{|issue| issue }
  issues = results.select{ |issue| issue.issue_id 
end
```

At this point, the `network_hosts/show.html.erb` view should show, but instead my log is showing a `302 Redirect`:

```
I, [2016-10-26T18:47:52.347035 #31947]  INFO -- : Started GET "/network_hosts/4673" for 12.33.233.231 at 2016-10-26 18:47:52 -0500
I, [2016-10-26T18:47:52.349154 #31947]  INFO -- : Processing by NetworkHostsController#show as HTML
I, [2016-10-26T18:47:52.349218 #31947]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"id"=>"4673"}
I, [2016-10-26T18:47:52.369483 #31947]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_back_button.html.erb (0.4ms)
I, [2016-10-26T18:47:52.377738 #31947]  INFO -- :   Rendered network_hosts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (10.2ms)
I, [2016-10-26T18:47:52.378656 #31947]  INFO -- : Redirected to https://www.myserver.com/
I, [2016-10-26T18:47:52.378816 #31947]  INFO -- : Completed 302 Found in 29ms (ActiveRecord: 9.7ms)
```

So, at this point, I don't see any reason there would be a redirect back to my root_url, do you?

The only thing I've been able to differentiate is that the `network_hosts#show` displays when there are no 'minor' issues (so 1 major/1 minor issues work, or 2 major/0 minor issues), but doesn't seem to work when there are 0 major and X minor issues.  Which leads me back to `get_host_issues` function in `application_helper#get_host_issues`, but from here I'm stuck.

Here is the `network_host/show.html.erb` (trimmed down):

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="major_issue_table" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Severity </th>
       <th>Code </th>
       <th>Problem </th>
       <th><span class="nobr">Action</span></th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @major_issues.to_enum.with_index(1).each do |result, index| %>
        <% issue = result.issue %>
          <tr>
             <td><%= issue_severity(issue) %></td>
             <td><%= issue.name %></td>
             <td><%= truncate(issue.problem, length: 100) %></td>
             <td>
                <a href='#' class='deferIssue' data-toggle='modal' data-tooltip='tooltip' data-resultid='<%= result.id %>' data-issueid='<%= issue.id %>' data-target='#deferIssueModal' title='Defer'><i class='fa fa-close'></i></a>
                <%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>'.html_safe, issue_path({id: issue.id, network_host: @network_host.id}), "data-toggle" => "tooltip", "title" => "View" %>
             </td>
          </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="x_content">
   <div class="table-responsive">
     <table id="minor_issue_table" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Severity </th>
               <th>Code </th>
               <th>Problem </th>
               <th><span class="nobr">Action</span></th>
             </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <% @minor_issues.to_enum.with_index(1).each do |result, index| %>
             <% issue = result %>
             <tr>
                <td><%= issue_severity(issue) %></td>
                <td><%= issue.name %></td>
                <td><%= truncate(issue.problem, length: 100) %></td>
                <td>
                  <a href='#' class='deferIssue' data-toggle='modal' data-tooltip='tooltip' data-resultid='<%= result.id %>' data-issueid='<%= issue.id %>' data-target='#deferHostModal' title='Defer'><i class='fa fa-close'></i></a>
                  <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Defer"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                  <%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>'.html_safe, issue_path(issue.id), "data-toggle" => "tooltip", "title" => "View" %>
                 </td>
              </tr>
            <% end %>
         </tbody>
     </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Update: Adding `layouts/_back_button.html.erb`**

```
<div class="row">
  <%= link_to "<span class='btn btn-default fa fa-home' style='margin-left:10px;'></span>".html_safe, :root %>
  <%= link_to "<span class='btn btn-default fa fa-mail-reply'></span>".html_safe, :back %>
</div>
```

Comment: The last line of get_host_issues is a syntactical error: `issues = results.select{ |issue| issue.issue_id`, at the very least you need a closing `}` character, but you probably want something more.

Comment: Also, on the previous line, `.collect {|issue| issue}` does basically nothing.

Comment: @philomory that was an error in copy/paste, the `}` is actually there.

Comment: What exactly do you think `issues = results.select{ |issue| issue.issue_id}` does? Because all it does is return all elements of `results` for which issue_id is not nil. Is that what it's supposed to do?

Comment: @philomory `Results` and `Issues` are individual models.  A result is unique and matches an issue.  I have to select the results that have `issue_id` in them.  In short, yes, your assumption is correct.

Comment: Ok, just checking. Anyway, the only other thing I can think that would be pertinent is, what's inside `layouts/_back_button.html.erb`? Nothing I've seen so far really suggests what the problem might be.

Comment: @philomory just added it... nothing crazy there either.  I really think it's within the `get_host_issues()` method.  But like I said, only seems to be related to show methods where it's only showing `minor` severity issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126773/discussion-between-philomory-and-godzilla74).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For major issues, you had this:

```
 <% @major_issues.to_enum.with_index(1).each do |result, index| %>
    <% issue = result.issue %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= issue_severity(issue) %></td>
        ...etc...
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Whereas for minor issues, you had this:

```
<% @minor_issues.to_enum.with_index(1).each do |result, index| %>
    <% issue = result %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= issue_severity(issue) %></td>
        ...etc...
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Notably, in the first case you are passing an `Issue` object to `issue_severity`, whereas in the second case you are passing a `Result` object.

The `Result` object isn't going to respond to the same methods as an `Issue` object, so somewhere inside `issue_severity`, a NoMethodError is going to get raised.

The redirect almost certainly comes from a [`rescue_from`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html) block in `ApplicationController`, which catches exceptions in controller/view code and allows you to do something *other* than show a generic 500 error (in this case, it's probably something akin to `rescue_from(Exception) { redirect_to :root }`, which isn't the greatest plan; it should at least be logging the exception before redirecting, but given the logs you posted, that's not happening.